Follow up to an old question
I saw the question here:
Can it be appropriate to orient a 2x4 "wide side out"?
I became very interested in this idea, but also have a few follow up questions..
Lets say I were to create a wall with a "standard thickness" of ~4.5" (3.5" from the 2x4 + 1" from 2x 0.5" drywall). However, instead of placing the 2x4s "thin side out" I put it "wide side out" on one face of the wall 16" apart on-center, then I repeat the same for the other face of the wall, but the 2x4s are staggered so the distance between the 2x4s is now 8" on-center. How would this impact the structural stability of the wall?
In my head This would be ideal for running plumbing and electrical, because you could just snake pipes and wire between the slats. If there is a concern about warping, running a 2x2 half way up would probably fix it. Additionally, this would make the 2 faces of the walls be 98% separated from each other which would allow for better noise reduction and dampening. You could also put in two layers of 1" foam board insulation to ensure everything stayed nice and cozy. Only downside to this seems to be that it would probably cost over 2x as much per wall done this way.
Please note I am NOT in construction and I am just a newbie DIYer.

Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question that stands alone. See [ask] and take the [tour].

I'm not sure how this would be a benefit for plumbing, except for maybe PEX.  You certainly couldn't run a drainpipe in such a wall.

Seems like a bit of a Frame Challenge!
I have actually heard of walls being built with the 2x4s in the usual orientation but with this sort of offset design and extra thickness - perhaps 5.5" between the drywall sheets instead of 3.5".
That keeps the structural stability - each wall is supported by full 2x4 studs. It lets you use standard methods for attaching cabinets and other things because you still have the full 2x4 studs available with the normal thickness. With a 5.5" gap at the bottom you would use 2x6s instead of 2x4s.
The extra 2" of gap does indeed make running electrical much easier. It doesn't really help for plumbing - for that you need around 9" or so to run plumbing between the 2x4s, and you would also have to support the plumbing with additional hardware because it wouldn't be supported directly by simply sitting in holes in the 2x4s.
And yes, it would provide much better noise reduction with the right type of insulation - that would be the biggest reason to do this. Another reason might be if you have a room that is kept significantly colder or warmer than the surrounding rooms and insulated for that reason.

Note that even the slight gap from rotating the 2x4s and having them alternate which surface of the wall they support is enough to prevent direct coupling of low frequency sounds from one side of the wall to the other through the studs, and to reduce heat loss via that path. Recording sound booths were sometimes built this way, filling the space between the two surfaces with sand to absorb and diffuse higher frequencies. The same opportunities and issues would apply for electrical and plumbing. Note that unless you increase the number of studs, there are fewer good places to mount shelves/TVs.

@keshlam I might not have been clear. This would require twice as many 2x4s because each wall of drywall needs the usual 16" (or possibly 24") support.

How would this impact the structural stability of the wall?

If you place a 2x4 across two saw horses wide side down and push down at the centre, it will easily flex. Now turn the 2x4 on its narrow end and push down on the center and it will be significantly stiffer. This is why studs are installed with the narrow end out.
Turning the studs 90 degrees (with the wide side facing outward) will cause the wall to flex when leaned against. Over time, this flexing may cause drywall cracking at the joints.
I don't see any benefit for electrical or plumbing. The space between the studs would be 1/2". This would provide insufficient space to install plumbing (which would actually make it harder and in some situations, impossible). You could run electrical wire through this gap, but you would have to staple it to each stud to support it. With a good drill bit, it is fairly fast to drill out the studs and then pull the wire through with the holes supporting the wire.
Building walls to provide noise separation:
If the goal is to provide better noise separation, these are some typical options:

Standard 2x4 wall add insulation between the studs (not shown).

Staggered 2x4 on a 2x6 plate add insulation in the void spaces (not shown).

Double walls separated with a 1" air gap and insulation between the studs (not shown). Maintaining the air gap is important. Be sure not to bridge the two walls if running plumbing or other items within the wall space.

This is really interesting! So even though there is more overall support for the drywall, since the support itself is weaker, it would eventually lead to issues with the drywall itself. That makes sense, and I didn't consider that. Your drawings are helpful, too, so thanks! I like the 2x4 on a 2x6 plate. it wouldn't increase the overall thickness of the walls by much, it would keep the support, and if I used a 1" foam board insulation between each stud (directly behind the drywall) it would leave a 1" air gap, too. Nice!

If your goal is to stop sound transmission, using a rockwool product intended for sound absolution over rigid thermal insulation would work better. If that is your goal, choose a product based on its acoustical performance (and cost). If the product is intended for sound absorption, the manufacturer will provide its acoustical performance. Insulations have different properties intended for different applications. Here is an example product: https://www.rockwool.com/north-america/products-and-applications/products/safensound/#Specifications&Sizes

For those who have not figured it out, my answer is the 2nd of the 3 sample images - 2x4 studs @ 16" staggered on 2x6 sill plate
